# Using the HTML5 <video> tag, the video plays when the image is clicked in iOS 7 and below, but in iOS 8.1 it plays when the app starts

Tags: ios, html

I am implementing a video feature in my application using the HTML5 <video> tag. I want the video to play only when the image is clicked. It's working properly in versions up to iOS 7, but in iOS 8.1, the video starts playing automatically after app initialization

I implemented it the following way:

```
<div style="margin-top:40px;">
  <img src="images/play-video-screen.jpg" onclick="Video()" value="Loading video...." />        </div>
<div>
    <video controls autoplay="true" id="welcomeVideo" src="video.mp4" style="display:none;width:2px">
        <source type="video/mp4" >
   </video>
</div>
<script>
    function Video() {
        document.getElementById('welcomeVideo').style.display="block";
               var videoEl = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        var sourceEl = videoEl.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
        sourceEl.src = 'video.mp4';
        videoEl.load();
    }
</script>
```

If I remove `autoplay="true"`, the video doesn't play at all, even when the image is clicked.

Comment: So, how is it not working properly, exactly?

Comment: my requirment is when i click on image then only video will play. but the actual problem after app initilization automatically video playing.

Comment: please check the above code, it's working properly up to iOS 7. problem in iOS 8 version device.

Comment: Have you considered not using `autoplay="true"`? (Previous versions of iOS may be ignoring autoplay as playing video is such a bandwidth/battery drain...)

Comment: after removing autoplay the video not working. when i click on image the video not playing. when i set autoplay to false the problem same like.

Comment: Looks like you've got a few logical mistakes here, but primarily, if you're not autoplaying the video, you have to do something in your click event handler to play the video when the image is clicked. Maybe try `videoEl.play()`? You might want to have a read up of the basics of HTML5 video and JS video control. There's lots of articles out there.

Comment: It's working properly up to iOS 7 vesions.

Comment: Looks like some subtlety has changed. I imagine, though, that the behaviour in the *earlier* iOS version was the broken one, not the behaviour in the current version. Anyway, I'm mostly just trying to get your question into a state where someone might actually reopen it; I'm no iOS HTML5 video expert...

Comment: thanks for respond my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Matt Gibson wrote, you may want to brush up on HTML video and audio. Some places to start:

[Mozilla Developer Network - Using HTML5 audio and video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

[Safari Developer Library - iOS Specific Considerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

(My rep isn't high enough to post more than two links, but do a Google search for "HTML Video Tag" for more.)

As for your code: there are a few things going on here that you will want to change to get this to work properly. Some of these are not necessary to get it working, but are more style advice.

Starting at the top:

1. Set an id for the image file container.
2. Set explicit width and height values (based on the video file's dimensions) for the video container. (These can be set in your JS using videoEl.setAttribute("width","___px") and videoEl.setAttribute("height","___px") if the size is variable from video to video.)
3. Remove the autoplay property and width style declaration.
4. Set variables in the JS for each of the elements you're touching; image container, video, and source elements. -- Note that I've called var only once in the function. The video element is actually the only one you "need" to do this for, as you are calling the other elements only once each, but I find it is good practice to define them all in their own variables, just in case you decide to manipulate any of these elements later. Also, getElementById is one of the fastest methods you can use to grab elements from the DOM, so use it when you can.
5. .load() the video as you did, but then .play() it.

Your code should resemble the following:

```
<div id="videoImg" style="margin-top:40px;">
    <img src="images/play-video-screen.jpg" onclick="Video()" value="Loading video...." />
</div>
<div>
    <video width="620" height="465" controls id="welcomeVideo" style="display:none;">
        <source id="video1" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<script>
    function Video() {
        var videoEl = document.getElementById('welcomeVideo'),
            sourceEl = document.getElementById('video1'),
            videoImg = document.getElementById('videoImg');
        videoImg.style.display="none";
        videoEl.style.display="block";
        sourceEl.src = 'video.mp4';
        videoEl.load();
        videoEl.play();
    }
</script>
```

Tested this on an iPad(3) running iOS7.1.2. Should work in iOS8 just fine.